# React - atom eslint config

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, eslint

I used to use 'eslint-config-rallycoding' with .eslintrc as follows:

```
}
"extends": "rallycoding"
}
```

Recently I started having errors with it which I could not solve despite googling so I switched to 'esling-config-react'

```
}
    "extends": "react"
    }
```

Now eslint complains:
'Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 2 (indent)'

I'm ok with 2. How can I change it accept 2?
Thanks

EDIT:

I checked the link suggested below and put the following in .eslintrc:

```
{
  "extends": "react",
  "rules": {
  "indent": ["error": 2]
  }
}
```

It results in the error in the console:

```
Configuration for rule "indent" is invalid:
    Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '{ error: 2 }').
 Error: /Users/wasteland/projects/react/shapes/.eslintrc:
    Configuration for rule "indent" is invalid:
    Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '{ error: 2 }').
```

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent

Comment: Thanks. Please see my update above.

Comment: The colon in the array should be a ,